# How can i get FSNamesystem of running NameNode in cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to get a running instance of FSNamesystem of HDFS.
However, it is somewhat complicated than I expected.

If I can get NameNode instance of running cluster, then it can be solved.
Is there anyone who know about this stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using conf file

Comment: How does it work? Can you give some specific example code for me?

Answer (score 0):

Actually FSNamesystem is used internally by the NameNode. At the same time, you will not able to create a NameNode instance because the NameNode is already running on the same port. So if your client is not a web application, it is hard to get the running NameNode instance. Maybe you can try using the secondary namenode for this purpose.